# Mysql Query two tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `route` and `combo`.

I have tried many queries (union and joins) with no success.

I would like to get results where no `Route` entry exists in the `combo` table for each `rt_num` in the `route` table where a `PDate` has entries. I am totally lost at this point.

`Route` Table

```
 id |    rt_num    | name |
----|--------------|------|
  1 | 123 east     | Ron  |
  2 | 2North       | Ted  |
  4 | 909          | Ted  |
```

`Combo` Table

```
 id | Route    | PDate               |
----|----------|---------------------|
  1 | 123 east | 2017-02-15 08:55:04 |
  2 | 2North   | 2017-02-16 10:55:04 |
```

`Results` Table

```
  rt_num  |    Pdate    |
----------|-------------|
123 east  | 2017-02-16  |
123 east  | 2017-02-17  |
2North    | 2017-02-15  |
2Notrh    | 2017-02-17  |
909       | 2017-02-15  |
909       | 2017-02-16  |
909       | 2017-02-17  |
```

More Info:

I have these 2 queries: 
SELECT DISTINCT r.rt_num , DATE_FORMAT(PDate,'%Y-%m-%d') from route r, combo;
 SELECT DISTINCT Route , DATE_FORMAT(PDate,'%Y-%m-%d') from combo; 
each return the data needed, I need to display them side by side matching rt_num with PDate to Route with PDate or NULL I hope this is a better explanation of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your results are not consistent with the sample input, can you fix this so that we can better understand what you need? What have you tried? What was the outcome and what was the problem with it?

Comment: and how you manage  the Pdate  ..why 3 pdate and not 100????

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT IN QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM `route` WHERE route.rt_num NOT IN (SELECT `Route ` FROM `combo`);
```

This query return value which is not available in combo table.

Answer (score 0):

The following Query does what I need it to do thanks to the help by Peter Brawley

```
select a.rt_num, a.tdate, b.Route
from ( 
  select distinct r.rt_num, date_format(t.PDdate,'%y-%m-%d') as tdate
  from route r 
  join combo t on r.rt_num IS NOT NULL    
  ) as a
left join (
  select distinct Route, date_format(PDdate,'%y-%m-%d') as pudate
  from combo
) as b on b.Route = a.rt_num and b.pudate = a.tdate ;
```